# how to get date without depending on systems date

Tags: android, kotlin, date, calendar

i want to get the date and time without using the systems date

i am using android studio emulator changing emulators date.

ex: todays date is `2 Feb 2023` but i change my devices date to `26 Feb 2023`. i still want it to display `2 Feb 2023` of todays date without depending on systems/device date

this is my code

```
var dateTime: String
val timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+8")
val calendar = Calendar.getInstance(timeZone)
val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy", Locale.US)
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(timeZone)
dateTime = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()).toString()
```

but it still returns depending on the systems date

Comment: Consider not using `TimeZone`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Those classes are troublesome and long outdated. Use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html). If for older Android, then through [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible but you need to make a network call for it

```
https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Kolkata
```

it will give you JSON like this

```
{
    "abbreviation": "IST",
    "client_ip": "122.170.105.143",
    "datetime": "2023-02-15T10:23:26.414176+05:30",
    "day_of_week": 3,
    "day_of_year": 46,
    "dst": false,
    "dst_from": null,
    "dst_offset": 0,
    "dst_until": null,
    "raw_offset": 19800,
    "timezone": "Asia/Kolkata",
    "unixtime": 1676436806,
    "utc_datetime": "2023-02-15T04:53:26.414176+00:00",
    "utc_offset": "+05:30",
    "week_number": 7
}
```

Once you have JSON in the response variable you can parse it like

```
 var response; //it will contains response 

  var datetime = response.getString("datetime");
  //if you want to parse it in readable format do it like this

  val informat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS")
  val outFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:s a")
  outputString = outFormat.format(informat.parse(datetime))
```

you may need to execute the network call in IO Thread you can use this

import in your gradle

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.9'
```

//your code

```
 CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            var response =
                JSONObject(URL("https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Kolkata").readText())

            val datetime = response.getString("datetime")
            val informat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS")
            val outFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:s a")
            var outputString = outFormat.format(informat.parse(datetime))
            binding.text.text = outputString
        }
```

Comment: when i use this code `val apiResponse = URL("http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Kolkata").readText()` it gives me an error of `java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to worldtimeapi.org not permitted` . when change `http` to `https` it also gives me error

Comment: use https  in url,  i have update my answer

Comment: i did change it to https but still gives me this eror [error code picture](https://imgur.com/a/npiKLyD)

Comment: run your URL() in the IO Thread instead on main thread using coroutines, or use Retrofit/Volley to get JSON data